# Верстка нестандартной навигации слайдера

Tags: css3, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте.
Каким образом можно сверстать нечто подобное, не используя картинки для отрисовки волн?
Спасибо.

[image]

Comment: css border-radius и перекрыть двумя квадратными div, либо canvas.

Comment: дизайнеры б#%@ь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, отрисовать интерфейс в canvas? SVG, вот это всё.. )